# Having to unplug & replug Wifi adapter everytime I boot into Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, usb

I have a brand new Desktop that I have a dual booted between Windows and Ubuntu. Every time I boot into Ubuntu, it says no Wifi adapter found even though I have my USB wifi adapter plugged in. I have to unplug it and replug it for Ubuntu to detect it.

I don't face the same issue in Windows.

Edit: Wireless-info outputs.

Before unplugging the adapter: https://pastebin.com/V0hg8mv8

After plugging the adapter back in: https://pastebin.com/agdppKyc

Comment: please run the wifi-script before unplugging your device while it is not working and please rerun the wifi-script while your wifi is working. https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014 Post the output at pastebin.com and add a link in your question. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Sorry for the delay. Ran the scripts and included the output links in the question.

Comment: Assuming you have a recent version of Ubuntu, `journalctl --follow /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` while you plug/unplug/plug will show you interesting messages.

Comment: @waltinator This is the output from running that command both before and after. https://pastebin.com/1eKC8PMU

Comment: <warn>  [1550467007.6845] wifi-wext: error getting interface name for ifindex 3, operation 'get-mode': No such device or address (6)

This is the only error looking error message I see!

Comment: from what i can see from the wifi-info-script: the command `lsusb` does not show any wifi adapter to be connected. so the questions are why and how to workaround or fix. I dont know why, and how to fix it, but as a workaround could be a script to enforce usb-detection. i dont know how to do that, i just found a webpage that wants to explain that, but i am not sure if this will work with the wifi-adapter too.   http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/12/create-a-button-to-restart-usb-in-ubuntu/